# How to skip empty line in psql \COPY in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, copy, psql

In PostgreSQL psql, how to make \copy command ignore empty lines in input file?

Here is the code to reproduce it,

```
create table t1(
  n1 int
);

echo "1
2

" > m.csv

psql> \copy t1(n1) FROM 'm.csv' (delimiter E'\t', NULL 'NULL', FORMAT CSV, HEADER false);

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY t1, line 3, column n1: ""
```

There is an empty line in file m.csv

```
cat m.csv
1
2
  << empty line
```

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL `COPY` is very strict, so there is not possibility to start `COPY` in tolerant mode. If it is possible, you can use [`COPY FROM PROGRAM`](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-3-feature-highlight-copy-tofrom-program/)

```
[pavel@nemesis ~]$ cat ~/data.csv 
10,20,30
40,50,60

70,80,90

psql -c "\copy f from program ' sed ''/^\s*$/d'' ~/data.csv ' csv" postgres
```